# Setting the class of a variable automatically in R?

Tags: r, class, character

I work with large datasets with individual ID coded as five digit numbers `20234`. Let's call it `DF$id.var`. The data are scattered over hundreds of surveys over dozens of years, so I'm constantly wrangling (loading, merging, subsetting, filtering) data.

**I never, ever** (EVER!) want this variable to be of `class` `numeric`, but every time I import files (.dta or .csv), R does this by default.

Littering my code with `DF$id.var <-as.character(DF$id.var)` is destroying my soul, and there must be a better way. Perhaps a single line of code at the beginning of my scripts or Rmarkdown files?

Something akin to:
*Hey R!...anytime you see anything called id.var, whether a column in a dataframe or a vector, ALWAYS class it `as.character`.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `read_delim()` family of functions from the `readr` package to read in the data and include the argument `col_types = cols(id.var = col_character())`, e.g.:

```
library(readr)

DF <- read_csv("example.csv", col_types = cols(id.var = col_character()))
```

Comment: Similarly, any of the base r "read." functions have this options.  See the `colClasses` argument in the help files for `read.csv()`, for example.

To do the above in base r:
`DF <- read.csv("example.csv", colClasses = c(id.var = "character"))`

Comment: This is great for a .csv - I unfortunately mostly have to open .dta files from Stata so I use `read_dta()`. I can't seem to get that working but perhaps this is more clear so I'll work at it. Thanks.

Comment: You could just write a function that wraps around `read_dta()` and transforms the variable.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks for actually making a constructive suggestion.